# What wavelength of light has the greatest rate of reflection off of ice?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction, ice, light-emitting-diodes

We are using a camera that is nearly flush against frosted ice (not perfectly clear, but pretty close).  We are currently using white LED's, but very little of the light gets reflected back into the camera.  Would a red light, for example, have a higher rate of reflection?  Or do we just need to get higher power LED's?

Comment: I think that the fact that frosted ice looks white under white light indicates that the amount of light reflected back from it is pretty much constant throughout the visible wavelength range. If it had significantly higher reflectivity for red light than for light of other colors, then it would appear to have a somewhat red or pinkish hue under white light.

Comment: Good point, the ice we are using to test is pretty much clear, but in the field the borehole ice tends to look blue.  This lines up with what @rob said in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick web search pulls up some data suggesting that [bluer light reflects from ice and snow better than red](http://web.pdx.edu/~emch/rs/vh5.html).
That's consistent with the observational fact that ice and water tend to look  blueish under white light.

[image: Snow and cloud reflectance]
[image]

Note that "visible light" is typically taken as 0.4--0.7 $\mu$m, but you would have to look at the spectrum of your LED to see what combination of primary colors it is combining to make white.

LEDs are [super cheap](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/531); you should experiment.